# Feature-installation style tree control in C++ with MFC

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, treeview

With reference to this installer control: [image: Installer]

My question is: is this dropdown-button style tree control available to use for other purposes within an MFC application?

My suspicion (after inspecting with Spy++) is that it is a heavily customised SysTreeView32, using wide icons that look like buttons, and that mouse-clicks on these icons are intercepted to display dropdown menus.

Does anyone know any better?

Comment: Your suspicion is correct: that is *exactly* what it is.

Comment: Thanks @NikB, that at least clarifies how I should go about reproducing the behaviour.